# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. Syntax issue?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

This is my SQLPLUS script, it seems to work with a comma (,) instead of || '|' || in the end, however, the following fails with

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 20000
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TAB OFF
SPOOL /home/oracle/scripts/dump_clean.txt

SELECT
TRANSLATE("ACTIONTIME",CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(13),'   ') as "ACTIONTIME"|| '|' ||
TRANSLATE("ACTIONCODE",CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(13),'   ') as "ACTIONCODE"|| '|' ||
TRANSLATE("COMMENTS",CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(13),'   ') as "COMMENTS"
FROM ASE_LIFECYCLEALARM1;


SPOOL OFF

QUIT
```

I need some help with understanding the issue here.

Comment: You need to remove the two embedded column aliases that are part of the concatenation expression. You can't have an alias in the middle of an expression

Comment: So, is this a "bad question" or do we need to submit the "answer" as an actual answer?